# No attribute 'enable_eager_execution' ? Already using TensorFlow 1.7

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

According to the TensorFlow Program's Guide ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager)), the following operations need `TensorFlow 1.7` but I got an error (see below).

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

Here is my set up.

I was doing this in `Google Colab`, following the instruction on this page ([link](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/02/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-tensorflow-keras-pytorch.html))

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

and then

```
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

and then

```
!pip install -q keras
```

and then using the instruction again from the [TensorFlow Programmer's Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager)

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

That should have upgraded to 1.7, but then I got the following error:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e1c25fd4f69c> in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
      2 import tensorflow as tf
----> 3 tf.enable_eager_execution()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution'
```

Any suggestion?

**Update**

I just found out that I was still at `TensorFlow 1.6` -- even after I tried the nightly build

```
print(tf.__version__)
1.6.0
```

Tried the nightly build

```
!pip install tf-nightly
print(tf.__version__)
1.6.0
```

So I guess my question is now this -- how do I upgrade to 1.7 in `Google Colab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to restart your kernel after the update if you've already imported TensorFlow before running the `pip upgrade`. (Runtime menu -> Restart runtime)

From a freshly started kernel process, the following prints 1.7 as expected for me:

```
!pip install -q -U tensorflow>=1.7
import tensorflow
tensorflow.__version__
```

Comment: Thanks! I am confused now.  Because at one point it seems I must use GPU acceleration, but now I also followed your suggestion (setting non-GPU) and it also worked.  So I think GPU acceleration is probably not required.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I've found my answer -- the notebook must use GPU hardware accelerator (Edit->Notebook settings).

Thanks!

**Update**

By now I am not sure that using GPU hardware accelerator is really the fix.  Please also see the other answer by Bob Smith.  I think the notebook may have some remembered state so I am not certain about the conclusions of my experimentation results.  You may want to try both suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Good news -- we just finished updating to TF 1.7, so you should have it available by default. :)